# IS the IJSER.org journal fake?

Tags: journals

I have submitted my research paper inot a journal IJSER.org . But I don't know whether they are fake or not. Have any idea about this Journal?

Comment: IJSER is not listed in SJR, so be careful.

Comment: This journal is not indexed in Thompson Reuters JCR, despite their claim to have an impact factor of 3.8, and was listed in [Beall's list of predatory journals](http://beallslist.weebly.com/standalone-journals.html). Draw your own conclusions.

Comment: Shouldn't you check this out before submitting your manuscript?

Comment: The best approach is to read some past articles and see if they appear to meet an appropriate standard.  If you have enough professional experience to write a publishable paper in a field, you should have no problem making such a judgment.  IJSER's papers don't look very good to me...

Comment: I don't understand how researchers can just submit to random journals they don't know. Please don't do this, you are helping those journals survive and everyone else gets these terrible spam mails about such journals because of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Impact factor doesn't look like legit and as stated by others it's not on the TR list of journals. In personal experience, this journal is kept on spamming my email inviting me to submit a paper. So, for an advice find other journals with good track record (i.e. studies, authors, etc.). :)

Answer (score 14):

It calls itself the *International Journal of **Scientific and Engineering** Research* (emphasis mine), and it published the following paper:

Nishad, T. M.  "Origin."  International Journal of Scientific & Engineering Research, Volume 8, Issue 7, July-2017, p. 1163.  [PDF](http://www.ijser.org/onlineResearchPaperViewer.aspx?Origin-07-2017.pdf).

I quote here the abstract and an excerpt:

> Abstract— In this paper the application of Soul Sets in Theology is introduced. Based on reference of various Holy Scriptures, a link among
>   some religions is derived.Using that relation, the generalized concept of God is discovered.
>
> ---
>
> **Theorem 1**: Origin O intersects with A.
>
> **Proof**: To prove that Origin intersects with A, It is
>   enough to show that there exist a soul object
>   x € O ∩ A.Consider a name of God “wadud”, The
>   stem of meaning of which is Love (say x) having
>   full judgment. Then x € A.It is obvious that Love
>   is a soul object. Since it has full judgment,
>   x € O.Hence x € O∩A .
>
> **APPLICATION IN THEOLOGY**
>
> - Theorem 1 helps a Devotee to identify the soul
>     objects in A and try to implement in life.
> - [...]

I rest my case.

Comment: You have to admit that using the euro currency sign for the "element of a set" relation is a creative touch.